# Magento 2 Custom module works perfectly in developer mode but doesn't show in production mode

Tags: magento, magento2

I created a custom module on developer mode that creates another tab in customer account and in the template I'm making a api call to another system of ours to display some information related to a customer attribute... All works well in developer mode once I switch to production mode it will not show the output of the template or the customer dash board.. anyone has any idea what may cause this?

I ran all the possible commands and deleted all the caches/generated code

```
setup:uprade
setup:di:compile 
rm -rf var/generation/*
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/log/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/session/*
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
rm -rf pub/static/*
rm -rf generated/metadata/* 
rm -rf generated/code/*
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_ES
```

It works in developer mode but once I switch to production is wont show. Also if I switch back to developer it works again.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It might related to permission, can you check permission to your module on developer mode and production mode?

Comment: I have the same permissions in both modes

Comment: Check nginx setting, e.g. turn pagespeed off

Comment: I tried that, still no change. I don't understand why it would work o developer mode but not on production. It's not only that the template is not being displayed the customer dashboard is missing in production as well